# Is it possible to set a php $_SESSION variable using Python so that I can keep access the variable?

Tags: python, php

I have a website written in php. example.com

there are two methods with the website

the first one example.com/login

```
<?php
class Login extends Controller{
public function index()
{
    if($_POST['pwd' == 1234]){
        $_SESSION['test'] = 1
    }
}
}
```

another on example.com/test

```
<?php
class Test extends Controller{
public function index(){
    if($_SESSION['test']){
        echo json_encode(['test' => 'you are a user']);
    }
}
}
```

I have a python file sending requests to example.com/login then example.com/test

```
import requests
url = 'example.com/'
headers = 'XXXX'
data = {'pwd': '1234'}
r = requests.post(url + 'login', data=data, headers=headers)
```

However, when the $_SESSION['test'] is not actually set.
I want to keep the $_SESSION variable I set in the example.com/login method
so that I can access other functionality on the website which need credentials

Comment: I would say "no". Python script in your example is the client, and can't influence the PHP Session. If that were allowed actually, it would mean a potential security issue as a session could be modified externally...

Comment: I have the impression that you're actually asking how to set up Python to send cookies. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I saw that question too, but I'm not sure whether that is related to what I want

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz Is there any ways to achieve my goal. I would like the python program to access mysql database and other function on the php website.
Thanks you so much